# PrimeFaces error messages are shown in different styles

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am developing a web-based application using JSF 2.3 Mojarra with PrimeFaces 7. My problem is that the error messages, which I define everywhere as

```
<p:message for="...">
    <p:autoUpdate/>
</p:message>
```

are sown in a different style depending on the page I am currently showing. I suspect this is due to some custom style(s) I use, but I am not sure.
I have the following cases:

1.) Two messages are shown, one of which disappears shortly after being shown. Both messages are shown in white color having a red background:

[image]

[image]

2.) Two messages are shown, one of which disappears shortly after being shown. This time one of them has its text in white and a background in red, while the other has its text in red, and the background in white:

[image]

[image]

3.) And, I have two more cases as well (however they appear on different pages)

3a.) Only one message is shown with its text in red and without an own background color - meaning that the background color is inherited from parent (which is white)

[image]

3.b) Only one message in shown with the text in white, and with a red background color.

Is there a way that I show ALL messages as in the case in (3a.)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I found out the reason for the case, in which two messages were shown. This was due to an additional component                            <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/> 
which was present in the template. I removed the component, and now only one message is shown. However, the problem with the styles sill persist.  I will try to construct a minimum working example for demonstration. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It sounds like you have custom CSS colliding with PF CSS.